# Unique constraint with foreign key

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, unique, postgresql-12

I have two Postgres tables with the following columns:

### **Command**

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | Integer Primary Key |
| name | VARCHAR(32) |

### **Option**

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | Integer Primary Key |
| name | VARCHAR(32) |
| command_id | FOREIGN KEY on COMMAND("id") |

I want to add another constraint where the Command `name` column and the Option `command_id` columns are tied, such that two commands can share the same name provided they are part of different options. How would I make such a constraint? Would it be better to add no constraint but only allow the backend to make the required checks before entering data?

Edit: I realized that I was overthinking it for my simple use case and that storing a JSON field would be fine enough. However, if the table structure happened to be more complex, then the question would still be valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the `name` from Command table is the same as `name` column in Option column. then that column in Option table is redundant and you can always fetch the name by FK that you already have (command_id).

but normally you can use `composite key` for your FK, for example :

```
 create table Options(
    id int primary key
    , name varchar(32)
    , command_id int
    , foreign key fk_name (name , command_id) references Command(name, id)
);
```

and of course name and id in command table should be part of candidate key.